# Django newbie: persistent error when trying to create my first django app

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django with this excellent book "Practical Django Projects". I was able to follow the steps of the book perfectly, but now I stumbled upon the following problem.
When creating the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/first-page/ as image below:

[image]

I found the following error page:

[image]

Slightly different of this one, announced on book (page 16):

[image]

Then, I openned the file urls.py and added to it the following line of code:

```
(r'', include ('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

And the code looks like this:

[image]

I saved urls.py and accessed http://127.0.0.1:8000/first-page/ again, finding the same error message above (nothing changed), when, according to the book, I should now have found this other error page:

[image]

As a result, after I create the directory and file default.html for templates, as follows:

[image]

And have changed the TEMPLATE_DIRS settings.py file like this:

[image]

Again, the http://127.0.0.1:8000/first-page/ shows that same error message when, this time should show this:

[image]

I have repeated several times the steps.

I'm using Python 2.6 and django 1.1 (the same version of the book).

Does anyone have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help.

It all seems so simple and straightforward. And yet, does not work!

Here my settings file code:

```
# Django settings for cms project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql',       'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = 'C:\Projetos\cms\cms.db'             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with    sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = ''

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cms.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or      "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'C:/Projetos/templates/',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',         
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Comment: For starting with Django, I'd rather suggest you use Python 2.7, Django 1.3 and do the official Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ Several things have changed since 1.1 that you will find useful later on.

Comment: Thanks, Danilo. I'll do that after reading  "Practical Django Projects", because I think this book is excellent.

Comment: Ah, it's written by James Bennett. He certainly knows what he's talking about. The book is probably great to get started with Django as a framework, but don't try to memorize too many things, as several Details have changed since :) (E.g. the newly introduced class based views and other important changes). I think reading the book first and then doing the tutorial is a good way to go.

Comment: Here are some links to help follow that book
http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2010/01/14/django.php (Source code)
http://blog.haydon.id.au/2008/08/notes-on-practical-django-projects.html (chapter by chapter help)

Comment: Are you restarting your development server after each change? Sometimes it doesn't pick up changes, and you need to restart manually.

Comment: The "template does not exist" error includes additional details on the template paths which were searched.  Please copy the **text** and update the question.  Screen shots are not as helpful as the actual text that shows the template search path.

Comment: Hi, S. Lott. I think I get the details. I'll edit my question now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get te "additional details on the template paths which were searched". How do I do that?

Comment: I found the answer to my first problem here: (thanks, mongoose_za):

http://blog.haydon.id.au/2008/08/2-your-first-django-site-simple-cms.html

"On page 15 you must make sure you edit the example.com site instead of adding a new site. You might have noticed in your settings.py the SITE_ID = 1. If you add a new site 127.0.0.1:8000 then that will have a SITE_ID of 2, and in the following section flatpage views filter by default on the current site which is 1."

I just change SITE_ID for 2 (instead of 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all errors was this (thanks, mongoose_za):

"On page 15 [of the book "Practical Django Projects"] you must make sure you edit the example.com site instead of adding a new site. You might have noticed in your settings.py the SITE_ID = 1. If you add a new site 127.0.0.1:8000 then that will have a SITE_ID of 2, and in the following section flatpage views filter by default on the current site which is 1."

So, I just change `SITE_ID = 2` (instead of 1) in settings.py, because I had added a new site 127.0.0.1:8000.

After that, I changed the path to my templates folder according to instructions on the book to:

```
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'C:/Projetos/templates/',
)
```

I found the expected result (the blank page "My first page")

I also have followed this advice:

"On p13 is where the first deviation from the older django kicks in. In your settings.py add 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware', (don't forget the comma) to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES."

All this was found on this great blog:

http://blog.haydon.id.au/2008/08/2-your-first-django-site-simple-cms.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: the template does not exist error is because you dont have the template

C:/Projects/templates/flatpages/default.html (also in your screenshot your template dir is spelled "Projetos")

Secondly: you shouldnt need to add any the url rule for flatpages. Flatpages works via middleware:

```
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
```

so within your settings file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TemplateDoesNotExist` error is not on your template, but on 500.html. There's an error in your code in your template or view and Django is responding with a 500 error. However, in development, you should have `DEBUG = True`, in which case Django will show a stacktrace instead of trying to load 500.html.

So the simple solution is to make `DEBUG = True` so you can see the real error and correct that. However, you'll still need 500.html when you finally launch, so you might as well go ahead and create that too.

Comment: Thanks, Pratt. I make `DEBUG = TRUE` because I thought that this was the way to "includes additional details on the template paths which were searched" (sugested by S. Lott). But I think I did the wrong thing.
After making DEBUG = True, how do I can see the error? (the brownser only shows the error page above, the one of the printscreen).